# Can't grab tabular content from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape tabular content from this [webpage](https://www.cbre.us/research-and-reports/COVID-19-Impact-on-Resident-Migration-Patterns). To locate the content, it is necessary to click on the ***12*** tab under this title `How to navigate the interactive report`. Upon clicking on that tab, the tabular content shows up at the bottom of that page under `Moves To Austin-Round Rock-Georgetown, TX MSA`.

When I observe network activity in chrome dev tools while populating the data manually, I could notice that a post http requests along with appropriate parameter is sent to this url `https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/CBREMigrationAnalysisv1extract/v/CBREMigrationAnalysis/sessions/F3E2227B603E4F5AB3156667A673CF9E-0:0/commands/tabdoc/set-active-story-point` ***in which the portion between `/sessions/` and `/commands/` is dynamic***.

However, I have been able to fetch that dynamic portion from [this url](https://public.tableau.com/views/CBREMigrationAnalysisv1extract/CBREMigrationAnalysis?:showVizHome=no&:embed=true&parentUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbre.us%2Fresearch-and-reports%2FCOVID-19-Impact-on-Resident-Migration-Patterns) on the fly before sending the post requests. Now, when I try with the following script, I get `500` status code.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

base = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/CBREMigrationAnalysisv1extract/CBREMigrationAnalysis?:showVizHome=no&:embed=true&parentUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbre.us%2Fresearch-and-reports%2FCOVID-19-Impact-on-Resident-Migration-Patterns'
link = 'https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/CBREMigrationAnalysisv1extract/v/CBREMigrationAnalysis/sessions/{}/commands/tabdoc/set-active-story-point'

payload = {
    'storyboard': 'CBRE Migration Analysis',
    'storyPointId': '14',
    'shouldAutoCapture': 'false',
    'shouldAutoRevert': 'true'
}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'x-newrelic-id': 'XA4CV19WGwIBV1RVBQQBUA==',
    'x-tsi-active-tab': 'CBRE%20Migration%20Analysis',
    'x-tsi-supports-accepted': 'true',
    'referer': base,
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(base)
    post_link = link.format(r.headers['X-Session-Id'])
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.post(post_link,data=payload)
    print(res.status_code)
    pprint(res.json()['vqlCmdResponse']['layoutStatus']['applicationPresModel'])
```

> How can I access tabular content from that page using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just implemented the storypoints feature in [this Tableau Scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping#tableau-scraper). Checkout [the storypoint section](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping/blob/master/README.md#story-points)

The following code will show all the storypoints, and go to storypoint with id `14` (equivalent to the storypoint with caption `12` in the UI). Then it gets the worksheet with name `P2P Table` into a pandas dataframe:

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/CBREMigrationAnalysisv1extract/CBREMigrationAnalysis'
ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
wb = ts.getWorkbook()

print(wb.getStoryPoints())
print("go to specific storypoint")
sp = wb.goToStoryPoint(storyPointId=14)

print(sp.getWorksheetNames())
print(sp.getWorksheet("P2P Table").data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/TableauCovid19CbreResidentMigration)